# Drop Temporary Table after execution of function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am executing a selfwritten `postgresql` function in a loop for several times from `Python`. I am using the `psycopg2` framework to do this.
The function I wrote hast the following structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    -- create a temporary table that should be deleted after  
    -- the functions finishes
    -- normally a CREATE TABLE ... would be here
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_t
        (
          seq integer,
          ...
        ) ON COMMIT DROP;

    -- now the insert    
    INSERT INTO temp_t
        SELECT
        ...

END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thats basically the python part

```
import time
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="...", dbname="some_db")
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in range(1, 11):
    print i
    print time.clock()
    cur.callproc("my_func")
    print time.clock()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

The error I get when I run the `python` script is:

```
---> relation "temp_t" already exists
```

Basically I want to measure how long it takes to execute the function. Doing that, the loop shall run several times. Storing the result of the `SELECT` in a temporary table is supposed to replace the `CREATE TABLE ...` part which would normally create the output table
Why doesnt `postgres` drop the function after I executed the function from `Python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary tables are dropped when the session ends. Since your session does not end with the function call, the second function call will try to create the table again. You need to alter your store function and to check whether the temporary table already exists and create it if it doesn't. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224806/how-can-i-detect-if-a-postgres-temporary-table-already-exists) post can help you in doing so.

Answer (score 3):

All the function calls in the loop are performed in a single transaction, so the temporary table is not dropped each time. Setting `autocommit` should change this behavior:

```
...
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="...", dbname="some_db")
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()
for i in range(1, 11):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another quick n dirty is to connect and disconnet after each function call.

```
import time
import psycopg2
for i in range(1, 11):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="...",   dbname="some_db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print i
    print time.clock()
    cur.callproc("my_func")
    print time.clock()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Not nice, but does the trick.